# Angular - How to add a counter Variable from template to html property?

Tags: html, angular

I have this HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let something of things; let i = index">
<span data-e2e="{{"abc" + i}}" class="checkmark"></span>
</ng-container>
```

I want to have this result rendered in the DOM:

```
<span data-e2e="abc0" class="checkmark"></span>
<span data-e2e="abc1" class="checkmark"></span>
...
```

But this `{{"abc" + i}}` wont work.

"abc" should be a string.
How can I do this, without saving the property (counter: i) to the components controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change,

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let something of things; let i = index">
<span data-e2e="{{"abc" + i}}" class="checkmark"></span>
</ng-container>
```

To:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let something of things; let i = index">
<span [attr.data-e2e]="'abc'+i" class="checkmark"> {{something}} </span>
</ng-container>
```

Here you should use `attr` as prefix and need to assign the value to custom attribute using property binding like, `[attr.data-e2e]="'abc'+i"`..

> [**Working Stackblitz..**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnjrdm)

Comment: @micro, Also edited my answer with your updated question of ```data-e2e``` .. Glad to help you..

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
<span data="normalString{{i}}" class="checkmark"></span>
```

`normalString` should be outside {{}}

also `data` attribute is not correct, read more how to properly add custom data attribute:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: This looks right, but it gives me: "Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'span'"

Comment: @micro check this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp, data attribute is not correct, you should change it

Comment: As the error says, there is no property called data on the `<span>` tag. If you want to display the string in DOM, move the string interpolation syntax between the opening and closing tag of `<span>`

Comment: The reason for this is, that i want to test this elements with protractor. The attribute is "data-e2e". So the result should be data-e2e="string0" etc.
I will update my question